# android allow app to start automatically permission code

Tags: android, flutter

I want to make Flutter location application, I wanted to send the location to api even when the application is closed.

The application works when it is closed, but there is a button on my phone (xiaomi mi 10) that closes the applications completely and clears the all cache. If I click on this the app doesn't work in background.
I used this package **https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator**

For this reason, I installed the workmanager every 15 minutes to make the app work again, the app manager didn't work at first, but when I opened these settings from the app's settings, it started to work.
[image]

When the user installs the first application, how can I get these permissions and make the auto-start part open by default, I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0):

In Java or Kotlin, you can use [this library](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter) but I don't know its solution in flutter. You should start an Intent to open the app setting and get the desire permission. for example for Xiaomi, you should start an Intent for `com.miui.securitycenter` package and `com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity` component. In java we use below code:

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.component = ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")
context.startActivity(intent)
```

I hope this be helpfull.